# Filtering command expression results for later use in script

Tags: variables, batch-file, command-line, scripting, command-prompt

I'm using the command "typeperf" to achieve a representation of the bandwidth used by a specific program (spotify in this example). I need to repeatedly retrieve a numerical value from the typeperf command, but typeperf's output contains unwanted text. Based on my research, I'm using "For /F" to store the typeperf output to a variable, but it seems the multi-line output of typeperf, and possibly its computational time are causing results that I did not expect. How can I get the variable "bndwdth" to hold the value "44433.214648"?

---

Base Command:

```
typeperf "\Process(spotify)\IO Data Bytes/sec" -sc 1
```

Output:

```
"(PDH-CSV 4.0)","\\name\Process(spotify)\IO Data Bytes/sec"
"10/28/2014 10:31:09.250","44433.214648"
```

---

Attempted Solution:

```
For /F "Tokens=2 delims=," %I in ('typeperf "\Process(spotify)\IO Data Bytes/sec" -sc 1') Do Set bndwdth=%I
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\name\Desktop>Set bndwdth="\\name\Process(spotify)\IO Data Bytes/sec"


C:\Users\name\Desktop>Set bndwdth="44433.214648"

C:\Users\name\Desktop>Set bndwdth= please wait...
```

---

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your actual code ECHOed the value each iteration in order for you to get multiple lines of output.

You could use FINDSTR to filter out unwanted lines.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %I in (
  'typeperf "\Process(spotify)\IO Data Bytes/sec" -sc 1^|findstr /rc:"../../.... ..:..:.."'
) do set "bndwdth=%I"
```

**Update in response to comment**

The `|` is the pipe operator that takes the output of the command on the left and directs it as input to the command on the right. The `|` is used within a FOR /F IN() clause. This clause undergoes an extra layer of parsing, so the `|` must be escaped as `^|`.

The FINDSTR `/RC:"string"` option is equivalent to `/R /C:"string"`. The `/C:"string"` option has two effects: 1) It treats the entire string as a single search term, even if there are spaces. 2) It defaults to treating the string as a literal search. The /R option overrides the default and causes the search to be treated as a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Would you mind explaining what the "1^" part does? Also, could you clarify what the "r" flag means in findstr? I found "/r : Uses search strings as regular expressions. Findstr interprets all metacharacters as regular expressions unless you use /l", but as someone who's only programming experience is in matlab this is a little difficult to understand. Thanks again!